# Find(query) return empty table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The first query return the rigth table with the matching value. From those matching value i want to query my other table to get all the information

```
 var query = { partition : req.params.partition }
    PartitionFilter.find(query)
    .then(partition => {
        if (!partition)
            return res.status(400).send({message : "Partition not found"})
        var query = {
            name : { $in : partition.filter }
        }
        Filter.find(query)
        .then(filter => {
            if (!filter)
                return res.status(400).send({message : "Filter not found "})
            return res.status(200).send(filter)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).send(err)
    })
```

Here is the schema of Filter

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var filterSchema = new Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
   },
   duration: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
   }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Filter', filterSchema);

'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var partitionfilterSchema = new Schema({
  filter: String,
  partition: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PartitionFilter', partitionfilterSchema);
```

It should return the table of all the matching filter but i get an empty table

Comment: What and where (which line) it is returning exactly? res.status(200).send(filter)? Could you post the result of partition.filter and the schema of Filter?

Comment: The line that return [] is res.status(200).send(filter).

Comment: Could you post the content of partition.filter and the schema of Filter?

Comment: FilterPartition join filter and partition. On the first query i get all the filter apply to a partition. What i want to do next to get informations of those filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I know how to solve your problem. Your first query returns an array of PartitionFilters so, when you reference to partition.filter in your second query, it is undefined because partition is an array (did you printed the result of the first query and the value of partition.filter?).

Your second query should be something like:

```
var query = {
    name: { $in: partition.map(function(elem){ return elem.filter; }) }
}
```

EDIT:

Although this may solve your problem, I think you could improve your code in different ways.

- As find queries return arrays, I suggest you rename the variables returned to plural (partitions, filters...).
- If you intended to get only one result, you should do a findOne but in the case of PartitionFilter, as partition is not defined as
  unique, there could be more than one result with the same partition
  and it would only return the first one.
- If it is not defined as unique because you want to make a ManyToOne relationship and there are several documents that relate a
  partition to a filter, what you should do is define partition as
  unique and filter as an array.
- In any case, you should relate the tables by ID (in this case, partitionFilter.filter should be an ID or an array of Filter IDs).
  For example:

  ```
  var partitionfilterSchema = new Schema({
      partition: {
          type: String,
          unique: true,
          required: true
      },
      filters: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Filter'
      }]
  });
  ```

  And your code could look like:

  ```
  var query = { partition : req.params.partition }
  PartitionFilter.findOne(query)
  .then(partition => {
      if (!partition)
          return res.status(400).send({message : "Partition not found"})

      var query = {
          _id: { $in: partition.filters }
      }

      Filter.find(query)
      .then(filter => {
          if (!filters || !filters.length)
              return res.status(400).send({message : "Filters not found "})
          return res.status(200).send(filters)
      })
      .catch(err =>{
          return res.status(500).send(err)
      })
  })
  .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).send(err)
  })
  ```